# JavaScript Trying to move a image with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm trying to move a image with a js script but it doesnt work, the console dont show anything.

```html
<html>

  <body onload ="do_timer()"> 
    <img id="the_image" src="https://s15-us2.ixquick.com/cgi-bin/serveimage?url=http:%2F%2Fstatic.allbackgrounds.com%2Fbg%2Forange.jpg&sp=fe8f01b8441f1d048c52dbd3721287a2" style="position: absolute; left:0px;"> 
  </body>
  <script>
    function do_timer() {
      var the_timer, x_position = 0
      , the_image;
      the_image = document.getElementById("the_image");
      x_position++;
      the_image.style.left = x_position;
      the_timer = setTimeout(do_timer, 50);
    }
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: To start with, your position is being reset to 0 before you add 1 each time, so it will never be more than left = 1. I would move all those var at the top to global, so you don't have to get a dom element each time, and you don't reset the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/137/)**.

1. You should place the tag `</body>` after the end of script (after tag `</script>`).
2. The variables should be defined before outside of the function so you will not reset them in every call :

   ```
   var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image;

   function do_timer() {
   ....
   ```
3. Set the image one time outside of the function :

   ```
   the_image = document.getElementById("the_image");
   ```
4. You need to add the unit sign `px` after the position value `x_position` so it will be :

   ```
   the_image.style.left = x_position+'px';
   ```
5. Better if you could separate the CSS code and avoid the inline style :

   ```
   #the_image{
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
   }
   ```

---

**FULL CODE :**

```
<body onload ="do_timer()"> 
    <img id="the_image" src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg">
    <script>
        var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image=document.getElementById("the_image");

        function do_timer() {
          x_position++;
          the_image.style.left = x_position+'px';
          the_timer = setTimeout(do_timer, 50);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var the_timer, x_position = 0, the_image=document.getElementById("the_image");

function do_timer() {
  x_position++;
  the_image.style.left = x_position+'px';
  the_timer = setTimeout(do_timer, 50);
}
```

```css
#the_image{
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body onload ="do_timer()"> 
  <img id="the_image" src="http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the position with a unit like px, cm, em, etc.

Ex:

```
element.style.left = x + 'px';
```